# ACTIVATE SIRI ON  IOS users can use Siri to go to places in the Flutter App (The same as HeadSpace App offers)

Tags: ios, flutter, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I want to add siri in my app, which helps IOS user to controll app by using siri.

I tried [flutter_siri_suggestions: ^2.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_siri_suggestions)
And [flutter_siri_shortcuts: ^0.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_siri_shortcuts)

By using this, I am only add siri to my app but i can not able controll my app like a page navigation and other withing the app.

I want to controll my whole app using siri
If i give command to siri that navigate to setting screen
siri should navigate my app to setting screen.